# i got an attribute error couldn't figure this one out so i had to ask here in python3.6 and the pandas data frame work

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
sapmle2000submission.astype('int32').dtypes
```

which raises an error:

---

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 sapmle2000submission.astype('int32').dtypes
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'

Can someone please help me to figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that the obejct `sapmle2000submission` is a `list`, not a pandas Series. 
You can convert it as `Series` and specify its `dtype`:

```
import pandas as pd
sapmle2000submission_series = pd.Series(sapmle2000submission, dtype='int32')
```

Comment: thank you  I tried the series it says for the pd.astype didn't work for me its the data from the CSV file thus we had to write the code for it is there any other means for the working this attribute error out.

Comment: i baically am asking for the astype attribute in the pandas.

Comment: I think you should add some sample data to let us better understand

Comment: the data is the from the kaggle challenge cat for dat the challenge 2 is just wanted to get the array for each of the data available thus giving me a chance to get the working aspects done to develop the algorithm.